# Entity Manager ORDER BY query with Sort Object

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, entitymanager

I am using the Entity-Manager and want to append the "ORDER BY" query comming from the Sort (org.springframework.data.domain.sort) Object.

The Sort object contains something like "id: DESC".
i can parse the Sort object as a String removing the condition and appending it to my query. the query would looks like this "SELECT p FROM projects ... ORDER BY p.id DESC"

Is there a better way to tackle this problem, any suggestions?

---

Sorry maybe my description is a bit missleading but i have a REST api and my method gets the Sort object inlcuding the field i need to order by and the direction. I cant easily order it ASC or DESC. its depending on the Sort object i own with the method usage.

Comment: Why would you have to parse a string? The Sort object is an object. Use its methods.

Comment: and how can i append the object itself to my query string without the ":" in between?

Comment: I see you are using spring. Check out Pageable and Sort with spring-data-jpa https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters

Comment: Sort is an Iterable<Sort.Order>. Each Sort.Order has a property, and an isDescending flag. Use a loop. And read the javadoc.

Comment: Sort has a direction attribute https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.Direction.html and even a descending method to do exactly what you need https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html#descending--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last week, i was checked for the same issue and changed my code as like below: it was worked Fine;sharing the same to you.

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = "SELECT p FROM projects";
entityManager.createQuery(strBuilder.toString());  
Iterator<Order> orderIterator = sort.iterator();
Order order = orderIterator.next();
strBuilder.append(" Order By ").append(order.getProperty()).append(" ")
                .append(order.getDirection().name());
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [descending](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html#descending--) method on you Sort object to get what you need.

```
query.orderBy(mySort.descending());
```